# Foreign Key field in django form not saving initialized value

Tags: python, django

I have a form with a foreign key field. The field is disabled and I initialized the value with `initial`. The value shows up but when I submit it, an error shows up: `'This field is required'`

views.py:

```
def updateTicket(request, ticket_id):
    ticketDetails = editTicket1.objects.filter(ticketID=ticket_id).last()
    updateTrouble = editTrouble(request.POST or None, instance=ticketDetails, initial={'ticketID': ticket_id})
    if updateTrouble.is_valid():
        updateTrouble.save()
```

forms.py:

```
ticketID = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=tblTicket.objects.all(),widget=forms.Select(attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}))
```

How come when I disable the field, a foreign key field, the server does not accept the value. Even with initialization, when posted, it submits a blank value.

Comment: Any answer for this? When `form` `fields` are `disabled`, the `form` content is not saved in the `database`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

from thee django docs, it states this for the form field: "By default, each Field class assumes the value is required, so if you pass an empty value – either None or the empty string ("") – then clean() will raise a ValidationError exception:"

So, instead you should have done this; ticketID = forms.ModelChoiceField(required:False, queryset=tblTicket.objects.all(),widget=forms.Select(attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}))

or in your Models you'd have set a blank argument to the field to False, but I'll suggest to do it in the Form.

Comment: I set required=False and now the error shows `"Column 'ticketID' cannot be null"`

Comment: how does it look in your model

Comment: `ticketID = models.ForeignKey(tblTicket)`

Comment: do one of this either ticketID = models.ForeignKey('tblTicket', null=False, blank=True, default='') or ticketID = models.ForeignKey('tblTicket', blank=False, default='')

Comment: I don't think you understand my question fully

Comment: I answered from what I know from the django doc and faced as issue

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this is the issue but I think your form will always by showing the `ticket_id` since this is given in the `initial` form option which overrides the `instance`.

It's described here in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

Also - if you want to correctly process the form I think you should expand the `update ticket` function like it is described in the docs: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view

The difference between the above example and your code will be in the `else` statement where instead of a blank form you initiate it using `initial` data like you provided in your code.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's fine if it shows up but I do want it to be disabled, not be able to be clicked by the user. Django does not accept the value when I disable the field. How come?